Unknown terminal: "/tmpERM"
On my Linux headless distro, i have a recurring error where when running some commands ("clear", "nvim", etc.), instead of the expected behaviour of running the command i get an error message saying the title.
I assume my TERM global is being set strangely somewhere, but does anyone know how i could discover where it is that the bad value is being set?
My current workaround is to have "export TERM=xterm" in my .bashrc, but that seems like just kicking the can down the road.

If your machine is headless, how do you connect to it?
